# Find occurrences of 7 or more Calls within any possible 7 day period within a Month

Tags: c#, sql-server

I work in the financial collections industry. There is a debt collection rule/law which states the following:

"A creditor must not contact the person who owes them money more than seven times within a 7-day period."

Given a List, where a Call has the following properties:

- CallDate - DateTime - Represents the date an outbound call was placed
- PhoneNumber - string - Represents the phone number dialed
- AccountNumber - string - Represents the account number of the account
  that was called

Suppose I have this list of calls already filtered to a given month's range:

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2024,1,1);
var endDate = new DateTime(2024,1,31);
var calls = callQuery.Where(x=> x.CallDate >= startDate && x.CallDate <= endDate).ToList();
```

**Problem:**

I need to find all occurrences of a violation. A violation is defined as any instance where a single account number was called more than 7 times in any possible consecutive 7 day period.

**Example:**
Month = January 2024 (01/01/2024 - 01/31/2024)

**Dates of Calls to Account Number 12345678:**

- 1/1
- 1/1 (two calls occurred same day)
- 1/2
- 1/3
- 1/4
- 1/7
- 1/28

***No violations, because more than 7 calls did NOT occur with any window of 7 days within the month***

**Dates of Calls to Account Number 987654321:**

- 1/10
- 1/11
- 1/11
- 1/11
- 1/13
- 1/14
- 1/16
- 1/16

***Violation, because more than 7 calls (8) occurred within a 7 day window (1/10-1/16)***

I have tried looking week by week, and grouping by account number. However this does not take into account the rolling "any possible" 7 day period. For example, if we take the month start and end ranges we can derive the start and end ranges of each week within the month, but violations can occur across multiple week start and ends. All that matters is that more than 7 calls were made within ANY possible 7 day window that falls within the month.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you sort the list by call date, then for any given call index N, you can see "does the call with index N+6 fall within 7 days of call N". If it does, there's a violation. Note that you've got a discrepancy in your description though: "A creditor must not contact the person who owes them money more than seven times within a 7-day period" vs "A violation is defined as any instance where a single account number was called 7 or more times in any given consecutive 7 day period". There's a difference between "7 or more times" and "more than 7 times".

Comment: @JonSkeet THANK YOU. I don't know why I couldn't think of this on my own, but that is a life saver. Greatly appreciate it. Also will fix that discrepancy.

Comment: Also: You cannot find all violations in that time period without having the data for the 6 days prior to that period. As-is, there will _never_ be any violation in the first 6 days ... same goes for the end of that period.

Comment: A rolling period complicates things so I would record calls and dates and when the call limit is exceeded check the the previous n-day period for number of calls. That way you're not trying to keep track of too many variables or get funky with queries just the call count. Obviously onvce the limit is reached the first time, the period check will be triggered on every new call. It is where I would start, not necessarily the final solution.

Comment: @Fildor Excellent point

Comment: What Database is in use? There may be already functions to query for windowed counts.

Comment: @Fildor Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: May be worthwhile to tag it.

Comment: @Fildor, is that true about no violation in the first 6 days? From the question it looks like multiple calls can be made in a sigle day - 1/11
1/11
1/11

Comment: @stemixrf yes, you are right. The point still stands that if calls are drawn out to the max (1/day), you'd need to know the days prior to not have false negatives. Even if you had 6 Calls on the 1st, and then none following, you wouldn't detect the violation caused by the 2 Calls that were made on the prior month's last day. So, you always need to "over-query" by one window-size to not have false negatives.

Comment: @Fildor yes this is correct. I have changed my query such that the startDate of calls is now the 1st of the month - 6 days, that way I can detect if a violation occurred on the 1st.

Comment: Not sure if you can move some of the computational effort into the SQL: [SELECT - WINDOW - (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-window-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by iterating over each account number and checking for violations within any possible 7-day period

```
var violations = new List<string>();
    foreach (var accountGroup in calls.GroupBy(call => call.AccountNumber))
    {
        var callDates = accountGroup.Select(call => call.CallDate).OrderBy(date => date).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i <= callDates.Count - 7; i++)
        {
            if ((callDates[i + 6] - callDates[i]).TotalDays < 7)
            {
                violations.Add(accountGroup.Key);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sliding window algorithms for this.
I will try to add some pseudo code for you to get started.

```
Dictionary<Date, int> dateCallMapping = new Dictionart<Date, int> 
{
    {1/1/2024, 2},
    {2/1/2024, 1},
    {3/1/2024, 1},
    {4/1/2024, 1},
    {7/1/2024, 1},
    {28/1/2024, 1}
}
```

After this create an initial filtered data

```
var numberOfCallsInTheFirst7Days = dateCallMapping
.Where(_=>_.Key >= startDate && _=>_.Key =< startDate+7)
.Select(_ => _.Value)
.Sum();

// this will give you 6 initially
```

Now you need to apply the sliding window to find a rolling violation

```
var currentStartDate = startDate;
var currentEndDate = startDate + 7;
var numberOfCalls = numberOfCallsInTheFirst7Days;
var violationCount = 0;

if(currentEndDate > endDate)
{
    // we have already counted all the possible number of calls. as the selected date range is less than 7 days
    return numberOfCalls >= 7 ? 1 : 0;
}

while(currentEndDate <= endDate)
{
    if(numberOfCalls >= 7)
    {
        violationCount++;
    }
    // now you need to remove the current start date count from the numberOfCalls;

    if(dateCallMapping.containsKey(currentStartDate))
    {
        numberOfCalls = numberOfCalls - dateCallMapping[currentStartDate];
    } 

    currentStartDate++;
    currentEndData++;

    if(dateCallMapping.containsKey(currentEndDate))
    {
        numberOfCalls = numberOfCalls+ dateCallMapping[currentEndDate];
    }
    
}

return violationCount;
```

Comment: Still has the border-problem. What if there's `{31/12/2023, 6}` ? -> 1/1/24 would not be marked as violation but it would _be_ one. (False-Negative)

Comment: I might be missing something. What is the start and end date you are considering?

If I assume the start date is 31/12/2023, where the user had made 6 calls, that would be taken into consideration in the initial `numberOfCallsInTheFirst7Days`

Comment: That assumption is wrong. You need data from _before_ the start date to evaluate the violation status _on_ the start date.

Comment: Just saw your comment in the original question. You are correct. It is not possible to detect if a violation has happened _on the start day_ without actually having call information of at least 7 days prior. The code here is based on the fact that I start counting the violations from the start of the provided date range.

Answer (score 0):

You should have provide sample data of 2-3 various example.

Try this,

```
Declare @StartDT datetime='2024-01-01'
Declare @EndDT datetime='2024-03-07'
Declare @Flg tinyint=6 -- 7 days occurence

declare @t table(phone varchar(50),Acc varchar(50),calldt Datetime)
insert into @t values(1,'123456','2024-01-01 15:00:00'),(1,'123456','2024-01-02 15:00:00')
,(1,'123456','2024-01-03 15:00:00'),(1,'123456','2024-01-04 15:00:00'),(1,'123456','2024-01-05 15:00:00')
,(1,'123456','2024-01-06 15:00:00')
,(1,'123456','2024-01-07 15:00:00'),(1,'1234567','2024-01-11 15:00:00')

;With CTE As
(
select *,lead(calldt,@Flg)over(partition by phone,acc order by calldt)Next7Days from @t 
where (calldt>=@StartDT and calldt<=@EndDT)
)
,CTE1 as(
select *,datediff(day,calldt,Next7Days)[Flag] from CTE
)
select * from CTE1 where Flag=@Flg
```

It work for me for whatever I have I understood your requirement.
Please provide correct sample data .Tell me for which sample data it is not working